# Is it bad to inject two ViewModel objects into a composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I'm using Hilt for injecting regular objects, as well as ViewModels. In a single part of my app, there is a composable function where I need to inject two ViewModel objects:

```
@Composable
fun AllProducts(
    allProductsViewModel: AllProductsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    authViewModel: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    //Stuff
}
```

Is it bad to inject two ViewModel objects rather than a single, as I do in the other parts of my application? Are there any downsides?

Comment: What does your `AuthViewModel` do? Does it provide you the details of your currently logged in user?

Comment: @ArpitShukla Yes, that is correct. I need the `AuthViewModel` because I need some details from the currently logged in User object. Is it bad?

Comment: I prefer keeping this information in a dedicated repository (say `AuthRepository`) and then I would inject that repository in the `AllProductsViewModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pulls the idea of having two models describing your ui state.

The only downside is how you later provide your `@PreviewParameter` in your composable previews.

Under assumption that there will be two models that describe your composable state,  you will need to tinker with the previews, where you will be forced to introduce third class that will just be used for the preview parameters and nowhere else.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate your help.